# Webpack 5 not bundling CSS url() asset modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, webpack-5

I'm trying to include a new font face in my React application. This is built using Webpack.

I've followed the webpack documentation of font bundling, https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts. For some reason this isn't finding the font files I've included.

I have specified the font files source when making a new font face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato Regular";

  src: url("../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");

  font-style: normal;
}
```

And then I have included this new font face in my styles like so

```
.button {
   font-family: "Lato Regular";
}
```

However, the webpack compiler produces errors when trying to compile this:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/index.scss) 21:37-102
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2' in 'G:\src\com\Web\app\src\styles'
resolve '../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2' in 'G:\src\com\Web\app\src\styles'
  using description file: G:\src\com\Web\app\package.json (relative path: ./src/styles)
    using description file: G:\src\com\Web\app\package.json (relative path: ./assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2)
      no extension
        G:\src\com\Web\app\assets\fonts\Lato-Regular.woff2 doesn't exist
      .ts
        G:\src\com\Web\app\assets\fonts\Lato-Regular.woff2.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        G:\src\com\Web\app\assets\fonts\Lato-Regular.woff2.tsx doesn't exist
      .js
        G:\src\com\Web\app\assets\fonts\Lato-Regular.woff2.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        G:\src\com\Web\app\assets\fonts\Lato-Regular.woff2 doesn't exist
 @ ./src/styles/index.scss 8:6-174 22:17-24 26:0-144 26:0-144 27:22-29 27:33-47 27:50-64
 @ ./src/index.tsx 4:0-29
```

These fonts do exist in the directory.

Heres the rules in my webpack.config.js.

```
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot"),
      filename: "js/[name].bundle.js",
      publicPath: "",
      assetModuleFilename: "static/[name][ext]",
    },
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            { loader: "style-loader" },
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                url: true,
              },
            },
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            { loader: "sass-loader" },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
          type: "asset",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-react",
                "@babel/preset-typescript",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

When importing images in .tsx files, the images do get bundles approriatley. This only occurs when using the CSS/SCSS url().

Comment: Your problem seems not to be your webpack.config, but the fact that the file does not exist where you tell it to be. The line `Can't resolve '../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2' in 'G:\src\com\Web\app\src\styles' resolve '../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2' in 'G:\src\com\Web\app\src\styles'` already tells you that it cannot find the file in that place, relative to that folder. Make sure that your file is where you claim it to be.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this now.

TLDR https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url

All url()'s used when using sass loader must be relative to the source scss file.

In my case, I had index.scss, and variables/fonts.scss. In index.scss, I imported the fonts file. This meant I had to change the url from

```
../../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2
```

to

```
../assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2
```

Comment: You're a gem! Thanks

Comment: Does anyone know how to deal with situation when url is a dynamic content served by server that is not accessible during compile time?